# 3SUM Implementation for 4-linear decision tree ( runtime of O(n^2/(logn/log logn)^2/3) )

Tags: python, algorithm

I was reading [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) and I saw that the current best known algorithm for 3SUM could solve the problem in O(n^2/(log(n)/log(log(n)))). I also saw that it could be solved in O(n^3/2) time using a 4-linear decision tree.

I was wondering if anyone knew where to find some implementation of either of these algorithms.

Pseudocode would be fine. I just want to figure out how to implement this myself in Python and understand how the algorithm works.

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for the [CS theory Stack Exchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: But here's the best known result.. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.05279.pdf